# GWT Google Visualization Column Chart using style roles

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I've made a column chart for my gwt project, and I am having trouble finding a way to change colours of my columns. There is only 1 serie and I am looking to use what they call style roles. Now I know how to do this in javascript as it is shown [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), but I am having trouble doing this in GWT?

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. What problem are you facing?

Comment: The GWT implementation has not been updated in a long time, so it may not support the column role feature that is necessary to change bar colors when you have only one series of data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get different colors, you should have different series. Try something like this (not tested)

```
  private DataTable createTable() {

        DataTable data = DataTable.create();       
        data.addRows(4); 

        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Metal");        
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Density");

        data.setValue(0, 0, "Copper" );
        data.setValue(1, 0, "Silver");
        data.setValue(2, 0, "Gold");
        data.setValue(3, 0, "Platinum" );

        data.setValue(0, 1, 9);// 9 is the value of the density  
        data.setValue(1, 1, 11 );     
        data.setValue(2, 1, 19);       
        data.setValue(3, 1, 21); 

        return data;   

    }

    }

    private Options createOptions() {
        Options options = Options.create();    
        String[] colorArray = {"#B87333","#C0C0C0","#FFD700","#E5E4E2"};
        options.setColors(colorArray);
        //Other options
         return options;
    }
```

**EDIT**

So my first solution didn't achieve the desired display, in order to get it working, a workaround is necessary because the API provided for GWT doesn't offer such option.

You should have a column and a row for each element. Also in order to have each bar aligned with its label the property `isStacked` has to be set to true. Here is the working example.

Other options is available [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options)

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.BarChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options;

public class TestBar implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
        Panel panel = RootPanel.get();
        panel.add(flowPanel);
        Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BarChart bar = new BarChart(createTable(), createOptions());
                flowPanel.add(bar);    
            }
        };
        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, BarChart.PACKAGE);
    }

    private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
        DataTable data = DataTable.create();
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Metal");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Copper");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Silver");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Gold");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Platinum");
        data.addRows(4);

        data.setValue(0, 0, "Copper");
        data.setValue(0, 1, 9);

        data.setValue(1, 0, "Silver");
        data.setValue(1, 2, 11);

        data.setValue(2, 0, "Gold");
        data.setValue(2, 3, 19);

        data.setValue(3, 0, "Platinum");
        data.setValue(3, 4, 21);

        return data;
    }

    private Options createOptions() {
        Options options = getNativeOptions();
        String[] colorArray = { "#B87333", "#C0C0C0", "#FFD700", "#E5E4E2" };
        options.setColors(colorArray);
        return options;
    }

    private native Options getNativeOptions() /*-{
        var options = @com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options::create()();
        options = {
            fontName : 'Calibri',
            fontSize : 12,
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            isStacked : true,
            orientation : 'horizontal',
            legend: { position: "bottom" },
        };
        return options;
    }-*/;
}
```

The result
[image]

Comment: You would need one density column for each metal to make that work.

Comment: I tried using the initial approach, and I did get the colouring I wanted, but the width of columns is really small now (because its expecting 3 other values for each) so it won't work. Any hints on how to do it with JSNI?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way having columns with different colors in a single series but I have tried a different way.

**I have created multiple series as many as no of columns and now I can set different color for each series.**

Visually it displays same to the end user.

**Here is code:**

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimpleLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.ChartLoader;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.ChartPackage;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.ColumnType;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.DataTable;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.corechart.ColumnChart;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.corechart.ColumnChartOptions;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.corechart.ColumnChartSeries;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.HAxis;
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.options.VAxis;

public class ChartDemo implements EntryPoint {
    private SimpleLayoutPanel layoutPanel;
    private ColumnChart chart;

    /*
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        addColumnChart();
    }

    private void addColumnChart() {
        Window.enableScrolling(false);
        Window.setMargin("0px");

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(getSimpleLayoutPanel());

        // Create the API Loader
        ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);
        chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSimpleLayoutPanel().setWidget(getChart());
                drawChart();
            }
        });
    }

    private SimpleLayoutPanel getSimpleLayoutPanel() {
        if (layoutPanel == null) {
            layoutPanel = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
        }
        return layoutPanel;
    }

    private Widget getChart() {
        if (chart == null) {
            chart = new ColumnChart();
        }
        return chart;
    }

    private void drawChart() {
        // Prepare the data
        DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Density");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Copper");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Silver");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Gold");
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Platinum");

        dataTable.addRows(1);

        dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "");
        dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 8.94);
        dataTable.setValue(0, 2, 10.49);
        dataTable.setValue(0, 3, 19.30);
        dataTable.setValue(0, 4, 21.45);

        // Draw the chart
        ColumnChartOptions options = ColumnChartOptions.create();
        options.setVAxis(VAxis.create("Density"));
        options.setHAxis(HAxis.create("Metel"));

        String[] colors = new String[] { "#b87333", "silver", "gold", "#e5e4e2" };
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            ColumnChartSeries series = ColumnChartSeries.create();
            series.setColor(colors[i]);
            options.setSeries(i, series);
        }
        options.setTitle("Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3");

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks very good, any chance the legend could be at the bottom, i.e. below each column, instead on the side?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting there seems to be a newer project that wraps this for GWT: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/, this allows roles to be set up quite easily, so per-bar colours, tooltips etc... are pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

In Server side you can use something like

```
        List<ColumnDescription> cd = new ArrayList<ColumnDescription>();
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("status", ValueType.TEXT, "STATUS"));
        cd.add(new ColumnDescription("count", ValueType.NUMBER, "COUNT"));
        ColumnDescription c = new ColumnDescription("role", ValueType.TEXT, "role");
        c.setCustomProperty("role", "style");
        cd.add(c);

        data.addColumns(cd);

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("TOTAL");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("totalApplications"));
        row.addCell("black");
        data.addRow(row);

        row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("PENDING");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("PendingApplications"));
        row.addCell("yellow");
        data.addRow(row);

        row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("APPROVED");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("approvedApplications"));
        row.addCell("green");
        data.addRow(row);

        row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("DECLINED");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("declinedApplications"));
        row.addCell("red");
        data.addRow(row);

        row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("CONDITIONAL");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("ConditionalApplications"));
        row.addCell("orange");
        data.addRow(row);

        row = new TableRow();
        row.addCell("WITHDRAWN");
        row.addCell(rs.getInt("WithdrawnApplications"));
        row.addCell("red");
        data.addRow(row);

        String json = JsonRenderer.renderDataTable(data, true, false, false).toString();
```

That creates JSON object like :

```
    {
        "cols":[{"id":"status","label":"STATUS","type":"string","pattern":""},
                {"id":"count","label":"COUNT","type":"number","pattern":""},   
                {"id":"role","label":"role","type":"string","pattern":"","p":{"role":"style"}}],

        "rows":[
               {"c":[{"v":"TOTAL"},{"v":10.0},{"v":"black"}]},{"c":[{"v":"PENDING"},
               {"v":2.0},{"v":"yellow"}]},{"c":[{"v":"APPROVED"},{"v":5.0},{"v":"green"}]},
               {"c":[{"v":"DECLINED"},{"v":1.0},{"v":"red"}]},{"c":[{"v":"CONDITIONAL"},
               {"v":1.0},{"v":"orange"}]},{"c":[{"v":"WITHDRAWN"},{"v":1.0},{"v":"red"}]}
               ]

     }
```

Displays like :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to extend the DataTable and include a style column with this:

```
public class StyledDataTable extends DataTable{

protected StyledDataTable(){}

  public final native void addStyleColumn()/*-{
    this.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  }-*/;

}
```

Then instantiate your table like this:

```
    StyledDataTable data = (StyledDataTable)DataTable.create();

    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, HEADER_1);
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, HEADER_2);
    data.addStyleColumn();
    data.setValue(0, 0, SOMEVALUE1);
    data.setValue(0, 1, SOMEVALUE2);
    data.setValue(0, 2, "color: green; opacity: 0.85");
    data.setValue(1, 0, SOMEVALUE3);
    data.setValue(1, 1, SOMEVALUE4);
    data.setValue(1, 2, "color: blue; opacity: 0.85");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend working answer provided by **garagebrewer**.

This is the full specs of Bar customization provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#coloring-bars

First of all, what we need to do is to create a class. Let's use following name (as **garagebrewer** called it in his post): "StyledDataTable"

```
import com.googlecode.gwt.charts.client.DataTable;

public class StyledDataTable extends DataTable {

    protected StyledDataTable(){}

    public final native void addStyleColumn()/*-{
      this.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
    }-*/;

}
```

Now, we can create our DataTable, Options and Chart:

```
private void initializeTestChart() {
    ChartLoader chartLoader = new ChartLoader(ChartPackage.CORECHART);

    chartLoader.loadApi(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StyledDataTable dataTable = (StyledDataTable)DataTable.create();

            int row = 0;
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Title");
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Column1");
            dataTable.addStyleColumn();
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Column2");
            dataTable.addStyleColumn();
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Column3");
            dataTable.addStyleColumn();
            dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Column4");
            dataTable.addStyleColumn();
            dataTable.addRows(2); 

            dataTable.setValue(row, 0, "ABC");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 1, 0.20);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 2, "color: red; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 3, 0.40);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 4, "color: yellow; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: white; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 5, 0.60);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 6, "color: yellow; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: white; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 7, 0.10);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 8, "color: red; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            row++;
            dataTable.setValue(row, 0, "DEF");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 1, 1.0);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 2, "color: green; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: white; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 3, 0.90);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 4, "color: green; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: white; stroke-opacity: 0.6;");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 5, 0.10);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 6, "color: red; opacity: 0.85");
            dataTable.setValue(row, 7, 0.50);
            dataTable.setValue(row, 8, "color: yellow; opacity: 0.85; stroke-color: blue; stroke-opacity: 1.0; stroke-width:6");

            BarChart barTestChart1 = new BarChart();
            barTestChart1.setWidth("100%");
            barTestChart1.setHeight("100%");

            // adding chart to a MaterialCard: "barTestChartCard1"
            barTestChartCard1.getCardContentPanel().add(barTestChart1);

            BarChartOptions barOpt1 = BarChartOptions.create();
            barOpt1.setColors("00bcd4", "26c6da", "4dd0e1", "80deea", "b2ebf2");
            barOpt1.setHeight(500);
            barOpt1.setEnableInteractivity(true);
            barOpt1.setIsStacked(false);
            HAxis h1 = HAxis.create();
            h1.setFormat("#%");
            barOpt1.setHAxis(h1);

            barTestChart1.draw(dataTable, barOpt1);
        }
    });
}
```

So, we were able to specify individual styles (color, stroke, opacity, etc.) for each bar, because we have added styleColumn after every our column.

That's it, BIG THANKS to **garagebrewer** for his working solution!

You can see the result of this code on this image:
[image]